# How can I select which interpolation technique will be used in a gdal command? (gdal_fillnodata.py)

Tags: gdal, interpolation

I work on Landsat 7 slc-off images and I would like to use the gdal_fillnodata.py command to fill-in the missing pixels. The problem that I have is that the gdal_fillnodata.py uses the "inverse distance weighting" (IDW) interpolation technique and I want to use the kriging geostatistical technique.

Do you have any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't.  There are no other algorithms defined in GDALFillNodata():

http://gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a0a079afef61968f224b159d48423d1c6

If the note mentioned in the docs applies to you:

> This algorithm is generally suitable for interpolating missing
>   regions of fairly continuously varying rasters (such as elevation
>   models for instance). It is also suitable for filling small holes and
>   cracks in more irregularly varying images (like airphotos). It is
>   generally not so great for interpolating a raster from sparse point
>   data - see the algorithms defined in gdal_grid.h for that case.

you are probably fine with GDALFillNodata().